# What is the best way to create multiple dummy variables in a data frame based on the original column's dtype being an object?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, list-comprehension, one-hot-encoding

I have a DataFrame with many columns that need to be dummied based on their dtype being an object. What is the fastest and most effective way to one hot encode/dummy these columns? List comprehension? Lambda? Regular functions and variable asignment? I will be using some columns in a linear regression model eventually. The data set is very large already so if I can do this without creating an excess amount of columns that'd be ideal. Here's a failed example of code I'm trying to make work:

```
[pd.get_dummies(col for col in df.columns if df.columns.dtype == 'object')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select_dtypes` to send the subset you want to turn into dummies. You can `concat` this back to the original DataFrame.

```
pd.get_dummies(df.select_dtypes('O'))
```

Otherwise you'd pass the entire DataFrame and would specify the columns in a list. You could use a list comprehension, or just check which `dtypes` are object.

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.dtypes.loc[lambda x: x == 'O'].index.tolist())
```